# Using react-stripe-js with styled-components

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, styled-components

I have an issue trying to use Stripe `CardNumberElement` and trying to style it using using `styled-components`

When I am trying to submit form that uses custom restyled CardNumberElement component I get this error:

`IntegrationError: A valid Element name must be provided. Valid Elements are: card, cardNumber, cardExpiry, cardCvc, postalCode, paymentRequestButton, iban, idealBank, p24Bank, auBankAccount, fpxBank; you passed: object.`

I have created an example of what I am trying to achive here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-stripe-js-forked-6b7lq

To reproduce enter card number: 4242 4242 4242 4242 Expiration date: 12/33 CVC: 233, press pay and open developer tools in Chrome.

I am aware that I can achieve the same effect by passing `options` prop, but I am using some old legacy components written with `styled-components` and I want to keep it consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue with your code is that you're supplying the wrapped/styled `StyledCardNumberElement` to Stripe's `getElement` method. The `getElement` method only accepts the element components provided by the library, or a string element-type as documented here:

https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/get_element

The fix would be to replace `StyledCardNumberElement` with `CardNumberElement` in your SplitForm component as shown below:

```
const payload = await stripe.handleCardSetup(
  "seti_xyz",
  elements.getElement(CardNumberElement)
);
```

With the above change, and after supplying a real setup intent ID and publishable key I was able to create a setup intent in your example app without any issues.